# rsync only n files from last subdirectory

Tags: linux, rsync

How can I rsync from remote to local only last three/four files from last subdirectory?

My directory structure:

```
dir1--
 ---dir1
    ---dir1
      ---file1
      ---file2
 ---dir2
```

I do not need all the files but a couple of them from each dir.

Answer (score 0):

rsync is probably not the best tools to solve all your problem; it's very specific.

perhaps could it be easier to develop a script to sort your file modifications to build a file list to sync. after that, rsync can use this file list.